# Why is the TRY-CATCH statement in the Stored Procedure is not working?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, try-catch

I have created a stored procedure which is used to update a value in a table and enter a record to another table. It should be done as follows.
After updating whether the mark is checked or not in the **Marks** table, a record should enter in the table **UpdatedMarkDetails** with the changed **MarkCode** and the changed value(previous value)
Also, I want to know when a non-existing **MarkCode** is entered. So I put a TRY-CATCH statement, but it is not working also. I'm also getting a 'Could not be bound' error in the query editor.
The Code is as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ChangeStatusOfMarks(@GivenMarkCode AS INT, @Value AS NVARCHAR(3))
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Marks
            SET dbo.Marks.IsChecked = @Value
            WHERE dbo.Marks.MarkCode = @GivenMarkCode
    END
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[UpdatedMarkDetails]
            ([UpdatedMarkCode],[MarkCode],[ExistedStatus])
            VALUES
            (NEWID(),
            SELECT Marks.MarkCode FROM dbo.Marks,
            SELECT Marks.IsChecked FROM dbo.Marks
            )
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
        ERROR_LINE() AS 'ERROR LINE',
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'ERROR MESSAGE',
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS 'ERROR SEVERITY'
END CATCH
```

I get the error as follows

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ChangeStatusOfMarks, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ChangeStatusOfMarks, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ChangeStatusOfMarks, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You are getting syntax errors because your insert is incorrect. Try/Catch doesn't help with syntax errors, only runtime errors.

Comment: Why are you Selecting the error and not throwing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have Syntax error, which means that the SQL to `ALTER` the SP is failing. It's nothing to do with the `TRY...CATCH`. Fix your syntax error:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ChangeStatusOfMarks (@GivenMarkCode AS int,
                                     @Value AS nvarchar(3))
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Marks
        SET dbo.Marks.IsChecked = @Value
        WHERE dbo.Marks.MarkCode = @GivenMarkCode;
    END;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[UpdatedMarkDetails] ([UpdatedMarkCode],
                                                [MarkCode],
                                                [ExistedStatus])
        VALUES (NEWID(), (SELECT Marks.MarkCode FROM dbo.Marks), (SELECT Marks.IsChecked FROM dbo.Marks));
    END;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_LINE() AS [ERROR LINE],
           ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ERROR MESSAGE],
           ERROR_SEVERITY() AS [ERROR SEVERITY];
END CATCH;
```

That **assumes** that the table `dbo.Marks` can only **ever** contain  1 row.

Personally, however, I would write the `INSERT` as:

```
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[UpdatedMarkDetails] ([UpdatedMarkCode],
                                                [MarkCode],
                                                [ExistedStatus])
        SELECT NEWID(),
               MarkCode,
               IsChecked
        FROM dbo.Marks;
```

*I'm also not sure why you have the `TRY...CATCH` here. You don't `THROW` the error, meaning that if the above fails, the error won't be propagated (unless that is your goal?). nor do you rollback the transaction on failure (or start one). That however, is a different question/answer, but just raising my point in answer that address the question asked.*

Comment: the try-catch statement was added just for experimentation. anyway, your answer gave me the solution. thanks @larnu